# In scriptwriting, how do you refer to disembodied voices that are not narrating the story?

Tags: creative-writing, screenwriting

In scriptwriting, how do you refer to disembodied voices that are not narrating the story?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZsJyCyGBSI

I was watching this and I was wondering what the "Long Long Man" part would appear in a script. It's not a narrator, so you can't do

> Narrator: "And that's when he fell."

So I am wondering how you would refer that disembodied voice in a script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
V.O.
```

... which stands for "Voice-Over"

https://screenwriting.io/what-is-the-difference-between-v-o-and-o-s/

> V.O. is used when the speaker is not physically in the scene. The speaker could be someone on the other end of a telephone line or radio broadcast, an unseen narrator, or a character’s inner-monologue.